# In pandas DataFrame assign multiple values

Tags: indexing, pandas, lambda

By grouping my dataframe by 'Hour' column I computed some values that are conditional to that hour column.

```
Out[15]: 
    normalized_entries  Hour
3             0.000563     3
6             0.001265     6
23            0.002392    23
7             0.002655     7
2             0.002962     2
15            0.003095    15
11            0.004472    11
19            0.005776    19
14            0.008059    14
5             0.008163     5
22            0.008319    22
10            0.009102    10
18            0.011684    18
4             0.016871     4
1             0.034377     1
8             0.038017     8
13            0.065110    13
0             0.074780     0
9             0.076391     9
17            0.087821    17
21            0.090782    21
16            0.119952    16
12            0.157843    12
20            0.169550    20
```

Question is how can I assign these values to my main dataframe dependend from the 'Hour' column.
What i tried myself:

```
    data = pandas.read_csv(turnstile_weather)
    data = data[['Hour','ENTRIESn_hourly']]
    data['normalized_entries'] = data['Hour']
    data_by_hour = data.groupby(['Hour'])
    data_by_totalh = data_by_h.sum()
    data_by_totalh = data_by_totalh.reset_index()
    m= data_by_totalh.sort(columns='ENTRIESn_hourly')
    m['normalized_entries']=m['ENTRIESn_hourly']/m['ENTRIESn_hourly'].sum()
   # plot = ggplot(data_by_totalh,aes('Hour','ENTRIESn_hourly')) + geom_histogram(position='stack',stat='identity')
    m2 = m[['normalized_entries','Hour']]
    for i in range(1,len(data['Hour'])):
        data['normalized_entries'][i] = m2['normalized_entries'][data['Hour'][i]]
```

I would imagine this should be solved with lambda map,but can't figure out how.
Thanks, Donatas

Comment: Can you post the original `turnstile_weather` csv file? or some raw data? For your question, you should use `groupby.apply` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use a merge, something like:

```
pd.merge(data, m2, on = 'Hour')
```

Comment: pd.merge did worked, but it also messed up my dataframe indexing.

Answer (score 0):

This will should work for you and keep your indexing:

```
data['normalized_entries']=data['Hour'].map(m2.set_index('Hour').to_dict()['normalized_entries'])
```